# dynamically color dynamic row data based on status feild in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am new to javascript. I have a table as shown below. I am inserting values dynamically into that table. I want to color particular records based on status of a row data.

I tried the below way. but only one record get coloured when multiple records are to be coloured. I am calling an Ajax call and getting some data which is to be displayed in the table

enter code here

```
  <div class="tb TBN" style="height:125px; border:none;">
                <table class="table table-condensed nchild customer" id="records_table">
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> 

$.map( data.response.data, function( item ) {    
var stat = item.status;    
if(stat=='A'){    

    trHTML += '<tr bgcolor="#0072B5" id="'+item.rCOxylane+'">' +
    '<td align = "center" width="5%"> <input type="radio" id="radio" class="radioDetails" name="empdetails" checked="checked" value="'+item.rCOxylane+'"/> </td>'+
    '<td id="decId" style="word-wrap:break-word;">' + item.rCOxylane + '</td>'+
    '<td id = "activeId" style ="display:none;"> '+item.status+' </td>'+
    '<td id="fname">' + fname + '</td>'+
    '<td id="lname">' + item.name2 + '</td>'+
    '<td id="mob">' + item.rCMobile + '</td>'+
    '<td id="emailid" style="word-wrap:break-word;">' + item.rCEmail + '</td>'+
    '<td id="landLine">' + item.rCLandline + '</td>'+
    '<td id="zipCode">' + item.rCZipcode + '</td>'+
    "<td><a id='EditCustomer' class='EditDetails' href='#EditDetails' role='button' data-backdrop='static' data-toggle='modal'>Edit Details</a></td>"+
    '</tr>'; 
    }else {
    trHTML += '<tr id="'+item.rCOxylane+'">' +
    '<td align = "center" width="5%"> <input type="radio" id="radio" class="radioDetails" name="empdetails" checked="checked" value="'+item.rCOxylane+'"/> </td>'+
    '<td id="decId" style="word-wrap:break-word;">' + item.rCOxylane + '</td>'+
    '<td id = "activeId" style ="display:none;"> '+item.status+' </td>'+
    '<td id="fname">' + fname + '</td>'+
    '<td id="lname">' + item.name2 + '</td>'+
    '<td id="mob">' + item.rCMobile + '</td>'+
    '<td id="emailid" style="word-wrap:break-word;">' + item.rCEmail + '</td>'+
    '<td id="landLine">' + item.rCLandline + '</td>'+
    '<td id="zipCode">' + item.rCZipcode + '</td>'+
    "<td><a id='EditCustomer' class='EditDetails' href='#EditDetails' role='button' data-backdrop='static' data-toggle='modal'>Edit Details</a></td>"+
    '</tr>'; 

    }
    });
```

If status == 'A', which ever the records contain status as 'A' they should be coloured but for me only 1 record got coloured. 
any solution will be more helpfull
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have multiple records, then don't do `<td><a id='EditCustomer' ... >` as they will be repeated several times. `ID` **must** be unique in the page.

Comment: What does `console.log(item.status)` gives you?

Comment: i hope you should use a loop to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that are wrong in that code:

- JavaScript code should be either inside `<script></script>` tags:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $.map( data.response.data, function( item ) {    
          var stat = item.status;    
          if(stat=='A'){
              //actions if true
          }
          else {
              //actions if false
          }
      });
  </script>
  ```

  or importing it from another file:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/script.js" />
  ```
- There's a lot of redundancy: if the big deal is only change the bgcolor of certain element, just operate over a fragment to concatenate later instead of asking to render all the code twice in both possible conditions:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      //Taking for granted jQuery was already loaded
      //  Nest it with $(document).ready() if you need all
      //  the HTML code loaded before JS execution
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $.map( data.response.data, function( item ) {    
              var stat = item.status;
              var color_frag = '';
              if(stat=='A'){
                  color_frag='bgcolor="#0072B5" ';
              }
              trHTML = '<tr '+color_frag+'id="'+item.rCOxylane+'">';
                  //Your cells here. AVOID Id duplications!
              trHTML+= '</tr>';
              $('.fillthis').append(trHTML);
          });
      });
  </script>

  <div class="tb TBN" style="height:125px; border:none;">
    <table class="table table-condensed nchild customer" id="records_table">
      <tbody class="fillthis">

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  ```

If you need to render several rows this way, you should use [loops](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).  If so, multiple duplicated IDs will be rendered the way you did it. As @D4V1D said, **ID must be unique** for each element in the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Use classes instead if you need to reference some of them at the same time, or concatenate unique IDs for each cell if you need more specific identification. Anyways, [jQuery](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjquery%2F&ei=CCwVVbH6Jsv7UOWlgOAK&usg=AFQjCNF4Z3hn1Eh9NLFxPzl79HdfFO7BeQ&sig2=t-eowOGnaLpgFm-hXH9P3g&bvm=bv.89381419,d.d24) has very powerful methods to reference DOM elements. You should research well about them.

**One more thing:** you should put all styling attributes in [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) files to improve efficiency, avoid redundancy and make the code easier to mantain.